# Como salvar um arquivo que possui espaços no nome no cURL?

Tags: libcurl

> O meio mais fácil que encontrei foi utilizar [**este caractere**](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2800) que é um `"Espaço em branco do padrão Braille"`, porém fica o dobro de um espaço normal. Sem contar que não sei se pode haver alguma incompatibilidade.

```
curl ftp://consulpres:123@ftp.tce.ma.gov.br:10021/2105922/2018/150033111/150014300/6-09.03.pdf -o /home/i3/maicom/bkp_sites/Gestão Balanço patrimonial.pdf
```

No cURL no momento no qual é salvo o arquivo PDF, o fato de haver espaços no nome do arquivo a ser salvo faz com que o cURL salve o arquivo com o nome incompleto.

Exemplos:

Esta é a maneira correta que ele deveria ser salvo.

> Gestão Balanço patrimonial.pdf

Porém ao encontrar um espaço, o cURL salva o nome incompleto e sem a extensão, ficando assim:

> Gestão

Comment: Coloque o nome entre aspas: `curl -o "/pasta/subpasta/nome do arquivo.ext" https://www.example.com/file.ext`

Comment: sim deu certo agora funciona como deveria, Muito obrigado amigo me ajudou muito